# Selenium find element by name

Tags: selenium

I have made a number of tests. I’m getting some strange behaviour when running inspect on a different machine. I run inspect on my local machine and I can find an element by its name however on the test machine it can’t find that element’s name when using inspect.

The first image is from my local machine where it can find the element.

[image]

The second one is the test machine which can't. They both have the same version of Office so I'm not sure why this would be happening. It's like it isn't treating it as an element
[image]